# Why cannot Typescript infer the type of the function argument here while Intellisense can?

Tags: typescript

Minimal example:

```js
type Event = { code: number, message: string }

type Handler = (event: Event) => void;

type HandlerMap<HandlerName extends string> = Record<HandlerName, Handler> & {
    name: string;
    defaultHandler: HandlerName;
};

export const registerHandlerMap = <HandlerName extends string>(
    map: HandlerMap<HandlerName>
) => {
    /* ... */
};

registerHandlerMap({
    name: "test",
    defaultHandler: "network-event",
    "network-event": (event) => console.log("Event", event.code)
                   // ~~~~~
                   // Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type.
});
```

If I change the `network-event` argument from `event` to `{}` and ask Intellisense to list the possible identifiers for destructuring, it correctly offers the following:

```js
({ … }) => console.log("Event", …)
// ^
// + (property) code: number
// + (property) message: string
```

However Typescript still throws the same error after I accept a suggestion:

```js
({ code }) => console.log("Event", code)
// ~~~~
// Binding element 'code' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Why can't Typescript figure the argument's type out while Intellisense clearly can?

Comment: [I can't reproduce](https://tsplay.dev/m3a4qw) IntelliSense doing anything reasonable.  Could you make sure you have a [mre] with explicit instructions for how to see what you're seeing?  Otherwise I don't know how to answer.

Comment: Also note that your question title and main question seem to be "why can't the compiler figure this out when IntelliSense can" and therefore everything in your question starting with "Can I somehow help" seems to be a second question.  It might be related, but they could have two quite different answers.  You might consider [sticking to one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/511366), possibly by deciding you only really want the answer to one of the questions (I'd guess it's the second one, but it's up to you) or maybe opening up two posts for two questions.

Comment: @jcalz thank you for taking a look at it! Yes the initial example was broken — I had left in `defaultHandler: "handler-1"` in the `registerHandlerMap` call, which caused the compiler to ignore the `"network-event"` property outright. I've now uploaded a [reproducable example in the TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/mLLPkm). I also removed the ancillary questions — I'm mostly interested in the disconnect between IntelliSense and TSC here, understanding that will hopefully answer the other questions I have automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#17520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17520), [microsoft/Typescript#25092](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25092), [microsoft/TypeScript#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872), and [microsoft/TypeScript#44999](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44999) for examples of similar problems.  The compiler uses heuristics to infer types, and sometimes the compiler gives up before everything has been successfully inferred.

---

In your call to `registerHandlerMap()`, you want the compiler to infer both the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `HandlerName` and the [contextual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) type of the `event` callback parameter.

Theoretically, a so-called "full [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) algorithm" to perform type inference, as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134), would be guaranteed to find both `"network-event"` for `HandlerName` and `Event` for `typeof event`.  But the TypeScript compiler does not use such an algorithm for inference.

Instead it uses some heuristic rules, that have some advantages like acceptable performance and ability to do partial inferences from partial code (see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17520#issuecomment-318935065) on a related issue).  These inference rules work pretty well in practice but there are definitely limitations where it gives up.  One situation where the compiler tends not to do things well is when you have multiple type dependencies on a single object, like the `map` parameter passed to `registerHandlerMap()`.

What happens here, more or less, is that the compiler makes two inference phases.  The first phase inspects each "context-insensitive" function parameter where any callback parameters are [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations)); the compiler tries to use these to infer generic type parameters for each one.  The second phase then inspects each "context-sensitive" function parameters and tries to infer any remaining generic type parameters and the contextual type of any unannotated callback parameters.

You have exactly one function parameter (`map`), and it is context sensitive.  So you get only one inference pass, where the compiler needs to infer `HandlerName` and `typeof event` at the same time.  It successfully infers `HandlerName` from the `defaultHandler` property, but at this time it still has no idea what `typeof event` is.  It could only possibly know this *after* `HandlerName` is inferred, but this is happening at the same time.

And then inference is over.  The compiler has inferred `"network-event"` for `HandlerName`, but inference for `typeof event` has failed.  It falls back to `any`, and you get an error if you've enabled [the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noImplicitAny).  If the compiler could make one more pass, it would presumably be able to infer `Event` for `typeof event`.  But there is no more processing time to be spent here, unfortunately.  The compiler is done with inferring types for that function call.

---

So then, what happens when you use [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_intellisense)?  Well, you are asking your IDE to show you type information about the call to `registerHandlerMap()` that the compiler has determined.  At this point, you get a little more processing time while your IDE plugs in the inferred `'network-event'` for `HandlerName`:

```
// on hover
// const registerHandlerMap: <"network-event">(
//    map: HandlerMap<"network-event">
// ) => void
```

And therefore depending on how you inspect the code, the compiler will be able to tell you things that assume `map` is a `HandlerMap<"network-event">`.  When you blank out `event` with `{}` and ask the compiler for property names to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) from the callback parameter, the compiler uses this inference to prompt you for things appropriate for `Parameters<HandlerMap<"network-event">["network-event"]>`.  But this extra bit of processing after compilation has completed doesn't fix the inference problem.  That has already failed, and will only succeed if you (for example) annotate the callback parameter.

---

Comment: This deserved so many more upvotes

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working example code

```
export const registerHandlerMap = <
  HandlerName extends string,
  O extends HandlerMap<HandlerName> // <-- Add this
>(map: O & HandlerMap<HandlerName>) => { // <-- and this O
    /* ... */
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsKBeKBvKBjA9gEwgC4pEBXAWwCMIAnAGigogGcWBDAc2KheFoCWiTlAC+AWABQU0JCgAJdonwAbOmigAKCAmQl4SYAEo0APihxcA-AG4pM8NEXK1tALLswAHmeq6AOXZmKAgAD2AkfBZefiFOc3QAJQg8WnwfJT9aQOZGX1dzADJMKSgy0iCePkFhO0lyqEIAM3YyFWB8uhJO7Mq60TqpMLBcWhQ8RD4oWghOAT46Ho8wDQyXAMqQ8Mjo6rjGAHktiOVopc81rJyIU1NNUvKKTxIj4vPvHuvTKRNUcwwHmUAPQAKigADpIVAQUCpAN7JIZnMFrR3poAfVyohKiQAEQRPi4+iAxoQFptDqZVx4xAQYAAd1GAGsALQ6QxEkm42kM5ls3TAXEkbQC37mCYsXBqcEqXCcTS4gzIIkhAXgvCEIwkho63VAoFQAB+xuN2t15qg+qgAAV2LRKhFaFAAOTs5DOqACChgFQCbACYAqEBQAAW7GiShdShAHtkEHBcKMNiAA)