# Typescript inference not properly done

Tags: typescript

I'm building an array component for react and I'm stuck in a typescript problem.
Let's say I have an array (named `data`) of typed objects and a function called "buildColumn" that will allow me to do something on a `key` of `data`.

so if I have data = [{a: 'a', b: 1}] and I do that `buildColumn('a', value => value.toUpperCase())`, I would like value to be inferred as a string, not 'string' | 'number'

Here is where I am currently:

```js
const data = [
  {
    str: '1',
    num: 3,
    bool: true,
  },
];
type DataType = typeof data[0]; // Please note that this is only for the examples, I won't know what kind of data will be used until we initialize the table, so it must be generic

type Column<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  key: K;
  title: string;
  render?: (value: T[K]) => ReactNode;
};

type TableProps<T> = {
  columns: Column<T, keyof T>[];
};

export function buildColumn<T, K extends keyof T>(
  key: K,
  title: string,
  render?: (value: T[K]) => ReactNode,
): { key: K; title: string; render?: (value: T[K]) => ReactNode } {
  return { key, title, render };
}
```

This is a simplified version of what I tried to build, my goal is now to use the function "createColumns" with the parameter `value` inside `render` directly inferred thank's to the type of `key`,

here is how I would like to use it:

```js
const columns: TableProps<DataType>['columns'] = [buildColumn('str', 'ID', str => str.toUpperCase())];
```

Sadly, typescript does not accept this and gives me the following error

```
TS2322: Type '{ key: "str"; title: string; render?: ((value: string) => ReactNode) | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Column<{ str: string; num: number; bool: boolean; }, "str" | "num" | "bool">'.   Types of property 'render' are incompatible.     Type '((value: string) => ReactNode) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((value: string | number | boolean) => ReactNode) | undefined'.       Type '(value: string) => ReactNode' is not assignable to type '(value: string | number | boolean) => ReactNode'.         Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.           Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.             Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Any way to deal with this ?

Comment: For info, I have this version with the builder pattern that is working, I will deal with it if I can't find better 


function useColumnBuilder<T>() {
  return function b<K extends keyof T>(
    key: K,
    title: string,
    r?: (value: T[K]) => ReactNode,
  ): { key: K; title: string; r?: (value: T[K]) => ReactNode } {  return { key, title, render }; }
}

const buildColumn = useColumnBuilder<DataType>();
const columns: TableProps<DataType>['columns'] = [buildColumn('str', 'STR', value => value.toUpperCase())];

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can achieve it -

```tsimport
const data = [
  {
    str: "1",
    num: 3,
    bool: true,
  },
] as const;

type DataType = (typeof data)[number];

type MapFromDiscriminatedUnion<
  T extends Record<string, any>,
  K extends keyof T = keyof T
> = K extends any
  ? ((arg: K) => void) extends (arg: infer Arg) => void
  ? {
    key: Arg extends string ? Arg : never;
    title: string;
    render: Arg extends string
    ? (value: T[Arg]) => ReactNode
    : never;
  }
  : never
  : never;

type Column<T extends Record<string, any>> = MapFromDiscriminatedUnion<T>;

type TableProps<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  columns: Column<T>[];
};

export function buildColumn<const T extends Record<string, any>>({ key, title, render }: Column<T>): Column<T> {
  return { key, title, render } as Column<T>;
}

// Here, although the types for columns are fine, however, the inference for the value parameter on the render
// function isn't made due to Typescript limitation
const columns: TableProps<DataType>["columns"] = [
      // ^? const columns: ({ key: "str"; title: string; render: (value: "1") => ReactNode; } | { key: “num”; title: string; render...
  buildColumn({ key: "str", title: "something", render: (value) => { return ""; }, }),
                                                       // ^? (parameter) value: any
  ];

// If you provide explicit type parameter to the function like this, the value is inferred from it
const cols: TableProps<DataType>["columns"] = [
    // ^? const columns: ({ key: "str"; title: string; render: (value: "1") => ReactNode; } | { key: “num”; title: string; render...
  buildColumn<DataType>({ key: "str", title: "something", render: (value) => { return ""; }, }),
                                                                  // ^? (parameter) value: "1"
  ];
```

Here's a [Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NnMnBw).

**NOTE**: As mentioned in the comments in the code itself, due to a [limitation of Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70319427/why-cannot-typescript-infer-the-type-of-the-function-argument-here-while-intelli), which is [it's processing algorithm](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17520#issuecomment-318935065), the value parameter doesn't get a type inferred unless we provide a generic parameter to the `buildColumn` function. Which I think would be okay for your use case.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response, however the point is that I can have this: `export function buildColumn<T extends DataType, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(
` since we do not know what is DataType until we use it.

Comment: I see. Could you update your question to mention the exact requirements? Like, what constraint would the `DataType` have and some use cases. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I added a note for that, this is the only constraint that seemed obvious to me but you are right I should have been more precise

Comment: It's only one comment added to the code, however, I'll update my answer to reflect what all I was able to make of re-reading your question again.