# How to infer types of deeply nested properties?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a descriptor object and uses the inferred type information to return a different object that has a nice API with strong typing.

The problem I'm running into is that TypeScript seems to only infer the types of nested properties if they are constrained to something like a union type. If they are constrained to a primitive type (e.g. `string`), they stay typed as that primitive and don't narrow to the actual literal that is passed in.

```
type ChildType = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

type ChildDescriptor<
    TName extends string = string,
    TType extends ChildType = ChildType,
> = {
    name: TName;
    type: TType;
};

type ParentDescriptor<
    TSomeProp extends string,
    TChildren extends ChildDescriptor[],
> = {
    someProp: TSomeProp;
    children: [...TChildren];
};

// Identity function so we can observe what types are inferred
const identity = <
    TSomeProp extends string,
    TChildren extends ChildDescriptor[],
>(
    descriptor: ParentDescriptor<TSomeProp, TChildren>,
) => descriptor;

const inferredValue = identity({
    someProp: 'I get inferred',
    children: [
        {
            name: 'I don\'t get inferred',
            type: 'foo',
        },
        {
            name: 'I don\'t get inferred either',
            type: 'baz',
        }
    ],
});

const [childA, childB] = inferredValue.children;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgSwDYBMAq5oF4oHIBmA9oblAD54BGAhgE6kW40BeuA3AFAeiSyKoARCAGcAxrQRhghWgB4OUKGgBy1ALbQIAD2AQAdimFRhwCXoDmUHCbPmANAqUZe23QaPxk6TFb5fnEA4AfL4A3o566hAAXEqqGpyKPDFOmJwAvpzcPgAKdPrAQmISUjLyimgAyoQaObSEYFCu+obGpggWDhWeqLT6TTotHvwoReKS0rQA2gC6wWGOwjUQdQ2xVcurYIlQoiN9erFTAHSnaD0oBzMZWQD0t1AAkigFCKBQ+ACueqLACIR6YyEKAAd2gomogMIlGEEFoADdoCC4NRgFBkkZ8lAOvg4X0UBxRACTNiXno-u8cOUlNVavVGs13G1bF0lBcDgM3K0LmMSpNZsEABSOF7FCYyWJ5A6FETjUpyDZ0hp2Nn7fRBBwASisIVFcsmWSJehJOLxEBQADVqEhPthSa9QILwvdFIoAHoAfkWm3psVwjyg5ggaNNtHxuFZey8ByOjkU4VdrsiGj9AZQAIAOrg0UGQ3pcWHzRG467kn6iCRWYp0lWoAnE1Bkyl-VB03oszng9j82aUE03nA4cWG+jMH6WMPXelHHMOOlNYbiWipo4o6gAIIOe6e1cjABCHG3XpmvlD+KtNogxzXl30nCAA)

In the example above, the `children` property of `inferredValue` is properly inferred as a tuple, and the `someProp` property as well as the `type` property of the children objects are narrowed to the specific literal types as I want. However, the `name` property of the child objects is staying typed as `string` and I'm not sure why.

I can work around this by adding `as const` after each value that's not narrowing, or even add it after each child object. It doesn't work any nest level lower than that because of the tuple, it becomes read-only and then it's hard to work with in an API with generics. In any case, I'd like to avoid this solution at all since adding a type assertion feels like a hack and not a real solution.

In the end, these descriptor objects will be generated with another piece of software I will build, so I will go with the workaround if I have to. I just wanted to see if there are other solutions that I'm not seeing.

The environment I'm working in is constrained to TypeScript 4.7.4, so I have to stick with features available in that version.

Comment: The best solution will work from typescript 5.0.0 as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WGXn2w). However, in your case [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgKrvw) should work. Let me know if it does so I can write an answer explaining; if not what am i missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Well, I'm willing to accept that as a solution. Having a single type assertion is much better than multiple. Since I can't use TypeScript 5 it looks like it might be my only option.

Comment: unfortunately, it is the only solution... Okay, I'll write an answer soon

Comment: @wonderflame There is a way about it, without `as const` and without `readonly`.

Comment: @0xts Can you elaborate? If your solution works I would prefer it as that feels cleaner.

Comment: Just posted an answer @MatthewBryant. Do you want me to explain it?

Comment: Has anyone considered using const generics here?

Comment: @kelsny I mentioned it in my comment, but OP is using Typescript 4.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it, if you don't want to use `as const` and make the array `readonly` -

```ts
type Cast<A, B> = A extends B ? A : B;

type Narrowable = string | number | bigint | boolean;

type Narrow<A> = Cast<
  A,
  [] | (A extends Narrowable ? A : never) | { [K in keyof A]: Narrow<A[K]> }
>;

type ChildType = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

type ChildDescriptor<
  TName extends string = string,
  TType extends ChildType = ChildType,
> = {
  name: TName;
  type: TType;
};

type ParentDescriptor<
  TSomeProp extends string,
  TChildren extends ChildDescriptor[],
> = {
  someProp: TSomeProp;
  children: [...TChildren];
};

// Identity function so we can observe what types are inferred
const identity = <
  TSomeProp extends string,
  TChildren extends ChildDescriptor[],
>(
  descriptor: ParentDescriptor<TSomeProp, Narrow<TChildren>>,
) => descriptor;

const inferredValue = identity({
  //    ^? const inferredValue: ParentDescriptor<"I get inferred", [{ name: "I don't get inferred"; type: "foo"; }, { name: "I don...
  someProp: 'I get inferred',
  children: [
    {
      name: "I don't get inferred",
      type: 'foo',
    },
    {
      name: "I don't get inferred either",
      type: 'baz',
    },
  ],
});

const [
  childA,
  //^? const childA: { name: "I don't get inferred"; type: "foo"; }
  childB,
  //^? const childB: { name: "I don't get inferred either"; type: "baz"; }
] = inferredValue.children;
```

Here's a [Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxyo7W).

### Explanation

The reason this works is because of the Typescript compiler scans the input, with it's algorithm, it first of all, scans the generics that are non-contextual and then the ones that are contextual, you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17520#issuecomment-318935065) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70319427/why-cannot-typescript-infer-the-type-of-the-function-argument-here-while-intelli).

So, if we use the `Narrow` utility, Typescript is forced to run the analysis for capturing the type on it, and since an `Array` is really an object, we map over all it's properties, exhaustively, as you can see that this is a recursive utility. [This](https://tsplay.dev/N5VEom) example would give you more insight into it -

```ts
type A = { [K in keyof ["some", "things"]]: ["some", "things"][K] }
//   ^? type A= { [x: number]: "some" | "things"; 0: “some"; 1: "things"; length: 2; toString: () => string; toLocaleString: (...
```

The intermediate `Cast` utility is where all the magic happens, it's really a trick that makes the compiler infer the type of A, through type B, essentially, if you add two generics and constraint one of them and then use it in another constrained generic, the compiler infers the type like `as const`, [for example](https://tsplay.dev/NDA51m) -

```ts
type Some = number | string;

function getValues<N extends Some, K extends Record<keyof K, N>>(arg: K) {
    return arg;
}

const value = getValues({ a: "something", b: "another thing" });
//    ^? const value: { a: "something"; b: “another thing”; }
```

Comment: Please explain how Cast prevents the compiler from widening the type

Comment: thanks, but I don't see anything related to Cast though